# have some Database questions (creating, connecting, security... etc)

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

i am quite new in programming, and have few questions regarding in play with the database...
(sorry if i make my post bit long)
I learn to work with Visual Studio 2008 using C#

**1. How to create the database? - is there a correct way for always?**
How i learned to do it:
- In the *Solution Explorer* i right click and then go to Add -> New Item... -> (select) Service-based Database -> (click) Add -> Finish. and that is all. Then in Solution Explorer i go in *app.config* and from there i can find the connection string that later on i can use it, and it looks like this:

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

So is this the correct way to create a database? Later on as i tested, i would need to install SQL Express to the computer that doesnt have visual studio in order this database could work for the program..
So is there better ways in creating a database, or this is just fine..

**2. How to secure the database from others to open it?**
With this i mean, someone else in visual studio might also open the tables and records and everything that is in the database. Simpy by just creating a new project, right clicking on "Server Explorer" window then "Add connection" as a data source to choose "Microsoft SQL Server Database File" then simply to browse the existing database. And after that, you have full access on the database. So any tips about this?

**3. How to create a database programmatically?**
So my idea here is that in the future i might want to create a new database that a program would use (that already is connected to another database). But have no idea on how i would use that connection string (how to get it), if the database is made using code (a button is clicked by the client for example to create a new database for a new "working year"). I have tried few from the examples i found on the internet for creating a database, but it always trows me an error...

I know that this questions are not specific, but i am new in programming and am bit unsure if i am doing the right way, and i know this place isn't like a forum, but i thought i might get some good answer that would guide me towards building my future knowledge...

P.S. I am quite young, and sorry if i made some mistakes in the writing (english is not my main language)...
(and if i was not clear in some way, please tell me and i ll try to be more clear)

Comment: You need a book

Answer (score 1):

> > 1. How to create the database? - is there a correct way for always?

For, small student projects it might be fine but in long run you will have to learn DBMS and Database design techniques. Some known databases are MS SQL, MySQL, Oracle, DB2 etc. Since you are working with Visual studio so i will suggest that you should install MS SQL free edition.

The more you start working with the latest technologies, the more ways you will find to create a database. Latest technologies add some sort of abstraction, so initially, just focus on creating a database in DBMS.

> > How to secure the database from others to open it?

Well, you need some sort of book to understand the database first.

In real world scenario's, mostly, the database is on a secured server and only database administrators have rights to change things in it. Developers usually have read only rights and they request the admins to run scripts the database. Secondly, the database that the developers get is usually encrypted i mean clients almost never give real data to the developers for security point of view.

Lastly, if you are using MS SQL then your database is always behind some sort of security like the Login box initially.

> > How to create a database programmatically?

Well, there are ways but since you are new you should try them for now. Post your problem here, and people will guide you with some easy way to achieve your task.

In the end, forums are great way to learn things. I do the same by asking questions to seniors. Keep it up and welcome to SO and programming, you will enjoy this community.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. As written in comment you need to start with a good book, I an sure you can something online.

One suggestion is to *always* first check Google. For example, searching for your third question brings up several [results](https://www.google.com/search?q=How%20to%20create%20a%20database%20programmatically?), and going through even the first couple will give you all the information you need.

When you have a specific question, ask here along with some code showing what you have tried and make your best attempt creating an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). I assure you the answers will be quick.

> **1. How to create the database? - is there a correct way for always?**

There is no correct way for always for anything. Most software create database programmatically, since you cannot expect your users to create the correct schema for you. This is typically either done in an installer or at start up.

> **2. How to secure the database from others to open it?**

There isn't any easy solution to this. One option is to ask the user for a password when creating the database and then again the ask the user every time they run the program. Some databases allow creating an encrypted properties files for starting the database server specifying a password.

In general, security is a very big topic. Again, a google search brings up interesting material but with less definitive guidelines

> **3. How to create a database programmatically?**

Check Google. This is a specific question but you should be able to find out the answer for yourself quite easily.